# ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] no elements in sequence after upgrading to NestJS v8 and RxJS v7

Tags: rxjs, observable, nestjs

After upgrading to NestJS v8, I had to upgrade my RxJS version as well from 6 to 7 then it started throwing `ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] no elements in sequence` error.

This is a sample method in one of the app services:

```
  show(): Observable<any> {
    return from(this.repository.fetch()).pipe(
      filter((data) => data.length > 0),
      map((data) => data.map((datum) => parseData(datum)),
    );
  }
```

While I had NestJS v7 and RxJS v6, the method was working just fine; in other words, if the `filter` operation is not passed, the `map` operator wouldn't be called at all and the Observable stops there.

But after upgrading to NestJS v8 and RxJS v7, if my repository does not return any data, the app starts throwing `ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] no elements in sequence` error.

A workaround I came up with is as follows:

```
  show(): Observable<any> {
    return from(this.repository.fetch()).pipe(
      filter((data) => data.length > 0),
      defaultIfEmpty([]),
      map((data) => data.map((datum) => parseData(datum)),
    );
  }
```

This way the error is gone but I have two more problems:

1- the `map` operator still runs which I do not want

2- the second one which is way more important to me is that I have to update all my services/methods which have a validation like this which is really crazy.

my dependencies are as follows:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.4.2",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.4.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.5"
  },
```

Comment: I've seen that error before when using the `first()` operator, if the subscription is completed without having emitted a value.  Are you using `first` anywhere?

Comment: Nest uses `lastValueFrom` under the hood. If there's no value emitted then there will be a problem. Try moving the `defaultIfEmpty` to _below_ the `map` operator

Comment: @BizzyBob no not at all

Comment: @JayMcDoniel it works the way you said. My question: Has NestJS v8 started using `lastValueFrom`? One more question: Isn't there a way without adding `defaultIfEmpty` because this way I have to update the whole source code to stop getting 500 errors. Any workaround?

Comment: Nest 8 upgraded to RxJS v7 which deprecated `toPromise` which is why we changed to `lastValueFrom`. Instead of adding this to every service you could add it to an `interceptor` and have the interceptor set the `defaultIfEmpty` for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We determined on Discord that an [interceptor](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors) could be used here to set the `defaultIfEmpty` like so:

```js
import {
  CallHandler,
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
  NestInterceptor
} from '@nestjs/common'
import { defaultIfEmpty } from 'rxjs/operators'

@Injectable()
export class DefaultIfEmptyInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler) {
    return next.handle().pipe(defaultIfEmpty([]))
  }
}
```

And then bind it globally in the `providers` part of the module with:

```js
import { DefaultIfEmptyInterceptor } from '../defaultIfEmpty.interceptor'
import { APP_INTERCEPTOR } from '@nestjs/core'
// ...

{
  provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
  useClass: DefaultIfEmptyInterceptor,
}
```

Comment: I'm brand new to NextJs/RxJs but seems like a bad idea to assume all endpoints will return `[]` if empty? What about ones that return objects?

Comment: Then `defaultIfEmpty({})`. You could use metadata via a decorator to set the default and retrieve it dynamically.